# Determine file type in Ruby

Tags: ruby, security, mime-types, content-type, file-type

How does one **reliably** determine a file's type? File extension analysis is not acceptable. There must be a rubyesque tool similar to the UNIX file(1) command?

This is regarding MIME or content type, not file system classifications, such as directory, file, or socket.

Answer (score 58):

There is a ruby binding to `libmagic` that does what you need. It is available as a gem named [ruby-filemagic](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-filemagic/versions/0.7.1):

```
gem install ruby-filemagic
```

Require `libmagic-dev`.

The documentation seems a little thin, but this should get you started:

```
$ irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'filemagic' 
=> true
irb(main):002:0> fm = FileMagic.new
=> #<FileMagic:0x7fd4afb0>
irb(main):003:0> fm.file('foo.zip') 
=> "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: According to http://grub.ath.cx/filemagic/CHANGELOG this gem doesn't seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: I'm happy to report that this gem is once again being actively maintained https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic

Comment: Works on Windows too.

Comment: Now again, this gem doesn't seem to be actively maintained. It's tagged "unmaintained" and "adopt-me" [on Github](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic).

Answer (score 35):

If you're on a Unix machine try this:

```
mimetype = `file -Ib #{path}`.gsub(/\n/,"")
```

I'm not aware of any pure Ruby solutions that work as reliably as 'file'.

Edited to add: depending what OS you are running you may need to use 'i' instead of 'I' to get file to return a mime-type.

Comment: To prevent nasty hackery, try using popen: `IO.popen(["file", "--brief", "--mime-type", path], in: :close, err: :close).read.chomp`

Comment: Yup, this or the `cocaine` gem.

Comment: @sj26 Each time I call `popen`, I get a zombie process because the IO object is not closed. To fix that, use a block: `IO.popen(["file", "--brief", "--mime-type", path], in: :close, err: :close) { |io| io.read.chomp }`

Comment: @sj26 what do you mean by "nasty hackery"?  Are backticks considered harmful?

Comment: @Pete interpolating potentially user supplied content into a command string like backticks is a potential security vulnerability. Using popen with an array of arguments prevents this category of exploit. :-)

Comment: Excellent point about zombies! `IO.popen(["file", "--brief", "--mime-type", path], &:read).chomp` works, too.

Answer (score 14):

I found shelling out to be the most reliable. For compatibility on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu Linux I used:

`file --mime -b myvideo.mp4`

**video/mp4; charset=binary**

Ubuntu also prints video codec information if it can which is pretty cool:

`file -b myvideo.mp4`

**ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2**

Comment: should be `file -b --mime-type myvideo.mp4` for web usage

Answer (score 10):

You can use this reliable method base on the magic header of the file :

```
def get_image_extension(local_file_path)
  png = Regexp.new("\x89PNG".force_encoding("binary"))
  jpg = Regexp.new("\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF".force_encoding("binary"))
  jpg2 = Regexp.new("\xff\xd8\xff\xe1(.*){2}Exif".force_encoding("binary"))
  case IO.read(local_file_path, 10)
  when /^GIF8/
    'gif'
  when /^#{png}/
    'png'
  when /^#{jpg}/
    'jpg'
  when /^#{jpg2}/
    'jpg'
  else
    mime_type = `file #{local_file_path} --mime-type`.gsub("\n", '') # Works on linux and mac
    raise UnprocessableEntity, "unknown file type" if !mime_type
    mime_type.split(':')[1].split('/')[1].gsub('x-', '').gsub(/jpeg/, 'jpg').gsub(/text/, 'txt').gsub(/x-/, '')
  end  
end
```

Comment: You also need to look for "\xff\xd8\xff\xdb" as a JPEG signature.

Answer (score 10):

This was added as a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56933/199712) but should really be its own answer:

```
path = # path to your file

IO.popen(
  ["file", "--brief", "--mime-type", path],
  in: :close, err: :close
) { |io| io.read.chomp }
```

I can confirm that it worked for me.

Comment: This works perfectly with the added bonus of not needing to add and maintain yet another gem.

Comment: This works but it trusts the extension as far as I know. It is probably good in most cases but using the magic number of the file is safer. In most cases it is obviously not a problem. The only reason why I mention this is because I just had to fix a bug where a file had ".jpeg" extension but was really a Gif. It was a pain to debug because most methods use the extension.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the File class, you can augment it with the following functions based on @PatrickRichie's answer:

```
class File
    def mime_type
        `file --brief --mime-type #{self.path}`.strip
    end

    def charset
        `file --brief --mime #{self.path}`.split(';').second.split('=').second.strip
    end
end
```

And, if you're using Ruby on Rails, you can drop this into config/initializers/file.rb and have available throughout your project.

Answer (score 5):

For those who came here by the search engine, a modern approach to find the MimeType in pure ruby is to use the [mimemagic](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic) gem.

```
require 'mimemagic'

MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open('tux.jpg')).type # => "image/jpeg"
```

If you feel that is safe to use only the file extension, then you can use the [mime-types](https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types) gem:

```
MIME::Types.type_for('tux.jpg') => [#<MIME::Type: image/jpeg>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give [shared-mime](http://shared-mime.rubyforge.org/) a try (gem install shared-mime-info).  Requires the use ofthe Freedesktop shared-mime-info library, but does both filename/extension checks as well as "magic" checks... tried giving it a whirl myself just now but I don't have the freedesktop shared-mime-info database installed and have to do "real work," unfortunately, but it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found [mimetype-fu](http://github.com/mattetti/mimetype-fu).

It seems to be the easiest reliable solution to get a file's MIME type.

The only caveat is that on a Windows machine it only uses the file extension, whereas on *Nix based  systems it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Ruby solution using magic bytes and returning a symbol for the matching type:

https://github.com/SixArm/sixarm_ruby_magic_number_type

I wrote it, so if you have suggestions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The best I found so far:

http://bogomips.org/mahoro.git/

Answer (score -1):

The ruby gem is well.
[mime-types for ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mime-types/)

Comment: This gem uses file extention to determine the type, not the content.

Answer (score -3):

You could give a go with [MIME::Types for Ruby](http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/).

> This library allows for the identification of a file’s likely MIME content type. The identification of MIME content type is based on a file’s filename extensions.

Comment: From Readme.txt: "The identification of MIME content type is based on a file‘s filename extensions". OP explicitly requested a method based on content analysis, not filename extension.