# How do I restrict file upload to certain extensions on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to allow files to be uploaded by having extensions of `.xls` and `.xlsx`. So, in the file selection window it must allow only files with these extension.

Using the below code for doing file upload in Rails

```
  <%= form_for @book, :url => book_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
      <div class="file_input" id="import">
        <%= f.file_field(:excel_file) %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

So, how do i allow files only with these (.xls, .xlsx) extensions ?

Comment: if you use carrierwave, you can define `extension_white_list`

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685834/663870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really because it's a security risk. Rather use a gem like `Paperclip` or `Carrierwave`. There are Railscasts for both to get you started on using them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `accept` option to [the `file_field` form helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-file_field):

```
<%= f.file_field(:excel_file, accept: "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") %>
```

MDN has [a list of common mime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) types for convenient reference.