# How can I get file extension from URI for an rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find File extensions like .gif,.jpg,.txt from the uri like http://testasp.vulnweb.com/avatars/noavatar.gif.

Answer (score 25):

You can use an extname method of File

```
url = "http://testasp.vulnweb.com/avatars/noavatar.gif"
File.extname(url) #=> .gif
```

Comment: You're assuming that the URL looks like a file path but that's not necessarily a valid assumption. What happens if there's a fragment or CGI parameters?

Answer (score 5):

There may be an easier way to do this but I'd recommend using a combination of the `Pathname` and `URI` libraries

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://testasp.vulnweb.com/avatars/noavatar.gif")

path = uri.path # /avatars/noavatar.gif

pathname = Pathname.new(path)

extension = pathname.extname # gif
```

See the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) and [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) library docs for more info.

Comment: Thanx for your replay...my another question is  how can i traverse through the source folder of a uri and get extensions?...

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Rails and you are talking about the request URL path's extension you can do this from a controller or helper:

```
File.extname(request.path)
```

Noting that request.path is a method of the request object in the rails controller.

And noting that request.path will never return nil.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked about extracting file extension, though take a look at this question/answers [Determine file type in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572/determine-file-type-in-ruby) it's better and more secure to rely on mime type rather than extension.