# How to check in rails uploaded file type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types

How can i see what type of file is comming?
For example, csv or xls...
Give code please...
I get file so:

```
aut_name = uploaded_io.original_filename
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads_prices', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      end
      as_load(aut_name)
```

Maybe by MIMO, but how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`uploaded_io.content_type` contains the MIME type of file.

So:

`uploaded_io.content_type == "text/csv"`

Comment: and how to check it? like: if uploaded_io.content_type == "csv"? or what

Comment: is this correct for xls? .content_type == "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it (content_type method) is not going to work if a user changes file extension. I've tested that in rails console and the changing the file extension also changes "content_type" output.

Found this SO question quite helpful:

[Determine file type in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572/determine-file-type-in-ruby)