# How can we restrict file uploads with valid file type but invalid content-type - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, mime-types, content-type

In my Rails web application, I have to upload **audio** and **video** files and for validating against **invalid file types**, I have used `jquery-validation engine` and I could do the same successfully. But, if I create a text file and change the extension from `.txt` to `.mp3`, e.g. `test.txt` to `test.mp3`, it will be taken as valid by jquery validation engine as the file extension is valid for an audio.

I want to check the content type also. When I opened the `test.mp3` in a player, it showed me an error message `Stream contains no data`. I want this kind of validation to be performed in the interface. Is it possible in Rails?

I'm using,

```
Rails 3.2.13

Ruby 2.0.0-dev
```

Hope anyone can help me out. Thanks :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to check [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) its a file attachment library for Active Record. This library is very straightforward to use and make validations with each content type. For example if you want to validate an Image you can by the next validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment :avatar, 
  :presence => true, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" },
  :size => { :in => 0..500.kilobytes }

end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can we validate the content-type in a scenario that I have furnished in the question?

Comment: If you really need to check the data of the file you can do it using FileMagic. Check this other question for know how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572/determine-file-type-in-ruby You can found the gem here https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic